# Looking to convert a coffeescript loop to javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'lm looking to convert this into javascript, although I can't read coffeescript all too well.
It looks like a while loop, but really not sure.

`for foo, i in foos when not x? or x > y`

Comment: "Converting this into JavaScript" is the single reason for CoffeeScript's existence. You can't have done *any* research before posting this question or you'd have landed on CoffeeScript.org which will do it for you right in-browser.

Comment: See that's why I find this site frustrating. You imply that I should have known that, and down vote my question as something that implies this is common knowledge. This was my first exposure to coffeescript so to me, it was a little unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I use is [coffeescript.org](http://www.coffeescript.org). Click the "Try CoffeeScript" tab, paste your CoffeeScript on the left and equivalent JavaScript displays to the right.

Your example is a for loop. CoffeeScript uses the `while` keyword for while loops and `until` for while not loops. So `for foo, i in foos when not x? or x > y` in JavaScript would look like this:

```
var foo, i, _i, _len;

for (i = _i = 0, _len = foos.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
    foo = foos[i];
    if ((typeof x === "undefined" || x === null) || x > y) {
        alert("Hello CoffeeScript!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, Thats actually what I had - Although Something is still a little off else where. Anyways my loop looks like this (done within angular)

angular.forEach(foos, function(foo, i) {
    if(x===null || x > y)
});